# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss

I want to get a list from DB.But im getting error.

My Controller like that:

```
public List<FuelType> fuelTypeList(){
        return entityManager.createQuery("Select c From FuelType c ").getResultList();
    }
```

And full trace like that:

```
SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Error Rendering View[/modul/vehicleDetail.xhtml]: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1361) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1289) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:261) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.domain.carsclass.controller.FuelTypeControlBean.fuelTypeList(FuelTypeControlBean.java:43) [carsClass-ejb.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.core.SynchronizationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SynchronizationInterceptor.java:35) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:186) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:104) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.domain.carsclass.controller.FuelTypeControlBean_$$_javassist_seam_17.fuelTypeList(FuelTypeControlBean_$$_javassist_seam_17.java) [carsClass-ejb.jar:]
    at org.domain.carsclass.session.FuelTypeFacade.getFuelTypeList(FuelTypeFacade.java:41) [carsClass-ejb.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.core.SynchronizationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SynchronizationInterceptor.java:35) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:186) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:104) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.domain.carsclass.session.FuelTypeFacade_$$_javassist_seam_65.getFuelTypeList(FuelTypeFacade_$$_javassist_seam_65.java) [carsClass-ejb.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invokeAndWrap(Reflections.java:144) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.callComponentMethod(Component.java:2313) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.createInstanceFromFactory(Component.java:2150) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstanceFromFactory(Component.java:2116) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:2024) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1996) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1990) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.Namespace.getComponentInstance(Namespace.java:55) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.Namespace.getComponentInstance(Namespace.java:50) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.el.SeamELResolver.resolveBase(SeamELResolver.java:148) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.el.SeamELResolver.getValue(SeamELResolver.java:51) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:44) [jboss-el.jar:1.0_02.CR6]
    at org.jboss.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186) [jboss-el.jar:1.0_02.CR6]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:129) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.ui.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:174) [jboss-seam-ui.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator.initializeItems(SelectItemsIterator.java:202) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator.hasNext(SelectItemsIterator.java:135) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderOptions(MenuRenderer.java:762) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderSelect(MenuRenderer.java:844) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:298) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeRow(PanelGridRenderer.java:148) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeStaticBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:110) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:63) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:49) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:70) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:57) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:204) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:121) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:70) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:57) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:204) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:121) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamViewHandler.renderView(SeamViewHandler.java:88) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.domain.carsclass.setting.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:48) [carsClass-ejb.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:397) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
```

Comment: I suppose that your problem is not connected with jsf. Take a look at exception. It says: `org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection `.

Comment: You have been facing this exception for a long time : `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection`. It has nothing to do with JSF (the container JBoss itself and Seam are not directly connected with the exception). The database connection is not opened for some unknown reasons which the current question does not cover. The question goes to Hibernate side.

Comment: @mertaksu did you figure this out? I am stuck at the same exception for some weird reason which breaks my app intermittently. If you got through this, please share what fixed it.